# How to insert a text before the table in a pdf created with jspdf-autotable

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Excuse my English expression.
I can't insert a text in front of a table made with jspdf autotable, I'm working on an Angular 8 project.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. The table seems static.

```
var conf={

    margin: {
      right: 5,
      left:5,
      bottom:5,
      top:5
    }
  }
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
import 'jspdf-autotable';

printPDF(){
  let columns = ["Ref", "Art",'Qte',"Remise","Prix TT"];
  let rows = [
      [1523, "TT", 785,'555',"555,555"],
      [1523, "TT", 785,'555',"555,555"],
      [1523, "TT", 785,'555',"555,555"],

  ];
 let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm',[1000,400],1);

doc.text(50,10,'my text');
  doc.autoTable(columns, rows,conf, ); 
  doc.save('table.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution, you just have to choose the margin value : top

such as

such as :
    var conf={

```
    margin: {
      ........
      top:50
    }
```

}